# How can I link an image in an app with a photo album image, so that likes in the app will like the image in the album?

Tags: facebook, photos

I need to get a way to be able to have "Likes" from an image inside an app be equivalent to Likes on an album.

For example, if image1 is liked in the app, then the album containing image1 also gains that like.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the plugin like button

[here the link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Comment: I've tried this, however it doesn't actually transfer the likes to the image in an album. When I try to link directly to the image, whenever you click the like button, it says you liked it, then instantly un-likes it.